# sum of cubes in its own loop ends ...

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $n$ is multiple of $3$, then sum of cubes of each digit of $n$ will end at $153$ in certain time. In case, if you got some other number then again apply sum of cubes of each digit of new number until you get the $153$. Of course, you cannot go further after $153$, as you get the same. If $n$ is not divisible by $3$, you may not get $153$. Why this is happening only for $n$, which is divisible by $3$?

raveena

---

One of the member, explained that, $3|d^3-d.$ But this is true even for any number of  d. Why 153 is so special, when we cubing and summing the all digits of a number ends with 153? kindly explain.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621971/repeating-number-when-n-is-multiple-of-3

Comment: @labbhattacharjee! this not correct reason. I need some good answer. but thank you for introducing the thread.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee! kindly explain more clearly and precisely.

Comment: i gave you a long and detailed explanation. Not sure what is that you do not understand. Take any number, divide it by 3 and take the remainder. Next add all the digits and then divide the total by 3 and take the remainder. Finally cube all the digits, add them and divide the sum of cubes by 3 and take the remainder? Do you get the same remainder? Try with a few different numbers. What do you see? Now do you see why this make 153 so special? Go back and read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take any digit and cube it. Then the resulting  number has the same remainder when you divide by $3$ as the original number. This is Fermat's little theorem
$$
d^3 \equiv d \mod 3
$$
Since sum of digits of a number has the same remainder as the number itself, adding the cubes of the digits does not change the remainder when divided by $3$. Now there are only 4 numbers with the property you state

$$
1^3+5^3+3^3= 153 \\
3^3+7^3+0^3 = 370 \\
3^3+7^3+1^3 = 371 \\
4^3+0^3+7^3 = 407
$$
Of these only 153 is divisible by $3$ so if you start with a number divisible by $3$, the process will never end or it will end on $153$.

If you want to know how to show that the process must end, you need to do more work.

Comment: ! it is quite interesting. But how you relate with fermat's little, I am little confuse. Can you clarify?

Comment: ! I assumed that $1^3 + 5^3+ 3^3$ = d and d = 153, then $d^3-d$ is divisible by 3. But this is not applicable for 370, 371 and 407. Why Fermats' little theorem is failed?

Comment: You need Fermat's theorem to show that cubing a number does not change the remainder when you divide by 3. So every time you add the cubes of the digits, the new number will have the same remainder as the original one. Example: number = 142. Divide by 3, the remainder is 1. Add the digits. You get 1+4+2=7. Divide 7 by 3 you get remainder 1. Now calculate $1^3+4^3+2^3$. You get 73. Divide this by $3$ and the remainder is still 1.  So the remainder will not change. So if you start with a number divisible by 3, then every  number you will get will be divisible by 3 and you will end with 153.

Comment: ! Sir, I got your example. My last question is prove that $d^3$ = d (mod 3) or $3|d^3-d$ mathematically.  Not by example. This will clear my all doubts.